# Trouble using python with Reticulate in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have been trying to debug this for about 8 hours now and I am getting really frustrated. I can't get reticulate to work and I have followed probably 15 tutorials step by step. I am able to import numpy and matplotlib just fine, but other packages in my environment, such as pandas and seaborn, return an error `ImportError: no module named pandas`. I just want to use python in R. It shouldn't be this hard. Things I have tried:

- Creating a new conda environment
- Creating a new virtual environment
- Uninstalling and reinstalling R and RStudio
- Creating an .Renviron and .Rprofile file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145643/unable-to-change-python-path-in-reticulate-r)
- Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXm8hPKFYCQ) exactly

Someone please help me. When I run `py_config()`, this is the output:

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:17:52)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]
numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.0

python versions found: 
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
```

I don't want to be using python 2.7 I don't think. I tried `use_python()` to no avail. I am about to give up, is there any last hope? It shouldn't be this hard!

Comment: Apple computers ship with Python 2 (though I wonder if that will change now that Python 2 is officially no longer supported). Perhaps before you do anything with R, first concentrate on getting Python 3 with pandas, numpy etc. running on your machine. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html

Comment: I do have python3 running on my machine with multiple conda environments. See ```/usr/local/bin/python3``` in the output above @JohnColeman.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of consistency problem. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63220597/4996248) will help. I agree that it shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: I've referenced that same question 3 times to no avail. I am so confused.

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58743111/4996248) (using `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/usr/bin/python3")` rather than modifying `.Renviron`) to the question that you linked to?

Comment: Same thing. numpy and matplotlib work, but not pandas or seaborn. py_configure() returns the same output as I list in the original post.