# R installation not finding anaconda packages

Tags: python, r, pandas

I was trying to install some packages in R and I have run into an error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘leiden’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'leiden', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

This is strange to me because I definitely have pandas:

```
$ conda list | grep pandas
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h0573a6f_0
```

Also which python seems to give me my anaconda installation:

```
/home/usrname/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I am installing these packages on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Ubuntu.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding another issue with a similar problem. Turns out I needed to activate the conda r-reticulate environment.

Take a look at a similar question here: [Python in R - Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220597/python-in-r-error-could-not-find-a-python-environment-for-usr-bin-python)