# How to install keras using R Studio on a Mac OS computer?

Tags: python, keras, installation, configuration, rstudio

If I run the following code:

```
install_keras()
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error in python_config_impl(python) :
```

Error 1 occurred running /usr/bin/python3:
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
running command ''/usr/bin/python3' '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/reticulate/config/config.py' 2>/dev/null' had status 1
2: In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
running command ''/usr/bin/python3' '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/reticulate/config/config.py' 2>/dev/null' had status 1

Somehow, I have managed to install keras (I don't remember how) as it shows up in my R packages.

But, when I run these codes:

```
library(keras)
is_keras_available()
```

I get this answer:

```
[1] FALSE
```

Warning message:
In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
running command ''/usr/bin/python3' '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/reticulate/config/config.py' 2>/dev/null' had status 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got exactly the same error as you when I tried to run install_keras(). I think the problem is when configuring Python in R, R couldn't find a Python environment for path '/usr/bin/python3'.

The following command line produces couple paths to choose from:

```
which -a python python3
```

What I did is that I install library 'reticulate' in R and run the following code.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/Users/[user_name]/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3") #Select the version of Python to be used by reticulate.
```

Then I called the library 'keras' again

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

And it worked!

Posts  that I found useful to this problem:

[Unable to change Python path in reticulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145643/unable-to-change-python-path-in-reticulate)

https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html

[Python in R - Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220597/python-in-r-error-could-not-find-a-python-environment-for-usr-bin-python)